# Can't send email using PHPMailer using Gmail(Failed to connect server)

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

i'm trying to send an email using PHPMailer. I've seen some topics about sending an email by Gmail servers using this package but i couldn't succeed.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587

$mail->Username = "myEmailAddress@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "MyGmailPassword";
$mail->setFrom('myEmailAddress@gmail.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('MyTargetEmail@example.com', 'John Doe');

$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->Body = 'Text to be sent';

if(!$mail->send()){
    echo 'message was not sent: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo 'Successfully sent';
}
```

my response :

```
2018-11-29 14:56:37 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
<br>
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
<br>
message was not sent: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: Maybe click that troubleshooting link?

Comment: i tried but nothing was there to help me fix. sth like pinging server and etc just works well for me but i still cant send.

Comment: [Read harder](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#encryption-flavours), and you'd have been better off if you'd started with [the gmail example code provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).

Comment: this code comes from there bro :)

Comment: No it doesn't; your code looks like a very old version, and it's simply wrong. The one I linked to is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the email to the wrong port/configuration. In your code you have it sent to Port 587 which handles stmp connections but you are sending it configured over ssl (which would need to be sent over port 465).

You **ONLY** need to change where it says ssl to "tls" and it will work.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
```

Comment: Nearly right. The difference is in the link I posted in a comment. Port 587 is SMTP submission, which typically uses explicit TLS and is sometimes known as SMTP+STARTTLS. SMTP on port 465 assumes TLS right from the start (i.e. it's implicit) and is known as SMTPS. In PHPMailer, the mode is chosen using the `SMTPSecure` property; the first mode is selected by using `tls` (**not** `smtp` as you said), the second with `ssl`.

Comment: I fixed it for you.

Comment: Tnx guys! it solved first problem but its still here with another title. it seems that i cant authenticate properly because i dont have secure connection. using different ports or connections doesn't solve problem unless i use a ssl connection, am i right? have you ever done sending email by gmail using phpmailer and not using any other configs than i did?

Comment: You're already using SSL; It's what TLS was called before 1998. You could always try reading the troubleshooting guide, which has lots to say about issues you might encounter when authenticating with google.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with composer

```
require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

```php
    <?php
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
        require 'vendor/autoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;enter code here
        $mail->Username = '@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = '';
        $mail->setFrom('@gmail.com', '');
        $mail->addReplyTo('@gmail.com', '');
        $mail->addAddress('@gmail.com', ' Name');
        $mail->Subject = 'This for Testing PHPMailer';
        //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('message.html'), __DIR__);
        $mail->Body = 'This is a plain text message body';
        //$mail->addAttachment('test.txt');
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'The email message was sent.';
        }
    ?>
```